# not able to use collate in sql query

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select hr_id from users where hr_id COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS='Rj001a'
                                    *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00920: invalid relational operator
```

Comment: You are using SQL Server syntax in Oracle.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - removed the comment

Answer (score 1):

You could use NLSSORT instead to specify collation in Oracle:

```
select hr_id 
from users 
where NLSSORT(hr_id, 'NLS_SORT = Latin_CI')  = NLSSORT('Rj001a', 'NLS_SORT = Latin_CI')
```